# Is there an event handler called after ComboBox.Items.Clear()?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to fire an event when a combo box has its items cleared and cannot seem to find the appropriate handler.

The code is simply:

```
comboBox.Items.Clear() // Fire event here.
```

I have tried `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectedValueChanged` with no luck.

Is there an event handler called after `Clear()`?

Comment: if you have code which clears the contents, why do you need an event to tell you that?  Just add a procedure to do what you want and call it  Events are more for telling you that the user just did something

Comment: Quick answer is I have a special class which tracks which controls are changed in a form. When this special class is constructed it attaches itself to a "change" event of each managed control. So I want the process of clearing items (which would clear any selected value) to be "attached" to this process without having to explicitly call it (dozens of times across several different forms).

Comment: keep in mind that `SelectedXXXXChanged` events can be triggered by user actions; clearing items cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no event you can catch as you can see in [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,32afdd0849411558).

You could handle the [`CB_RESETCONTENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775878(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x014B /* CB_RESETCONTENT */)
    {
        // do something
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: What about ComboBox `SizeChanged` event? Just curious.

Comment: @Rahul: No: `Occurs when the Size property value changes` I think this is only the outer control, not the inner.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.

Comment: Just a question.let say I have a nother program that trigers the same msg.then it would triger in his app also.or not?so for now I'am thinking it could be very unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no event you can call.
you can make a Sub and call it after you use "comboBox.Items.Clear()"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
comboBox.Items.Clear()
AfterClear()
End Sub

Private Sub AfterClear()
'Your code
End Sub
```